# Comma delimited input for a powershell function

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array, powershell-2.0

I currently have a function that I made that gets a list of all files in a directory and then adds them to an array called $FileListArray.

I want to add an option that lets me specify the file extensions to exclude from the arrary so that I could call the function as follows **ListFiles -FilesToList "c:\test" –exclude “avi,txt,bmp”** and this would then ignore files with any of the file extensions I have put in.

My Function so far

```
Function ListFiles($FilesToList){

$FileListArray = @()
    Foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $FilesToList -Force -Recurse  | Where-Object {$_.attributes -notlike "Directory"})
    {
        $FileListArray += ,@($file.name,$file.fullname,$File.Extension)
    }

    }

Listfiles  -FilesToList "c:\tools"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function ListFiles($Path,$Exclude)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $FilesToList -Force -Recurse  | 
    Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -notmatch ($Exclude -join '|') }
}

Listfiles -Pathc:\tools –Exclude avi,txt,bmp
```

Comment: Thanks this worked could you just point me to an artical or some thing that explains these commands !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -notmatch ($Exclude -join '|') , i have just not seen any thing like this , I just learn mostly by doing.

Comment: PSIsContainer is a property that tells you if the current object is a container object (folder in the case of a filesystem provider) or a file. Type 'help about_Join' for more info on the join operator.

Comment: Ok thanks thanks makes it a lot clearer and the ! means Not , so not a container, one thing i dont get is the join command read the help so if i read it correctly then the join would do this !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -notmatch (avi,txt,bmp,exe) but that bit of code does not work  and does the | mean that it joins every thing in the pipe. sorry again to bother you just really like understanding stuff

Comment: I used join to create a regular expression pattern 'avi|txt|bmp' that can be used with the notmatch operator. The '|' sign represents an OR, 'avi' or 'txt' or 'bmp'. Without it you'd need to compare three times, one for each extension: where {$_.extension -notmatch 'avi' -or $_.extension -notmatch 'txt' -or $_.extension -notmatch 'bmp'}